# Проблемы с массивом "тип массива "float [n]" является неназначаемым"

Tags: c++

Всем привет,учить недавно начал С++ пишу простые программки

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n; 
    cout << "введите n: ";
    cin >> n; 
    float a, b, h, s, f[n];
    cout << "введите a: ";
    cin >> a; 
    cout << "введите b: ";
    cin >> b;
    if (b>a) { 

        h = (b - a) / n;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            f[i] = (a + (i - 0.5) * h) / (1 + pow((a + (i - 0.5) * h), 2));
            s = s + f[i];
        }
        s = s*h;
        cout << "(f1+f2+f3+..+fn)*h= " << s << endl;    
    }
    else {

        cout << "введены данные не удовлетворяют условие (b>a)" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ну при  компиляции VS 2015 ругается на то что "выражение не определяется константой" и "тип массива "float [n]" является неназначаемым"
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где допущена ошибка и как ее исправить. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: `f[n]` это для С, в С++ это не сильно корректно. Есть смысл если это с++ использовать `vector<float>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас несколько проблем имеется в программе.

В C++ отсутствуют массивы переменной длины (Variable Length Arrays - VLA), размер которых можно задавать во время выполнения программы. В C++ размер массива должен быть известен на этапе компиляции, а потому задается константным выражением. Некоторые компиляторы имеют собственные расширения языка C++, которые включают поддержку массивов переменной длины, но, тем не менее, это не соответствует стандарту C++, а потому такой код будет не переносим.

Поэтому вам придется динамически распределять массив заданной пользователем длины. Например,

```
Float *f = new float[n];
```

Или если вы хотите, чтобы элементы массива были инициализированы 0, то

```
Float *f = new float[n]();
```

Но тогда вам придется самостоятельно удалять выделенную память при завершении программы. Например,

```
delete [] f;
```

Такой подход чреват возникновением ошибок, связанных с утечкой памяти, так как программисты порой забывают вызывать оператор `delete []` для выделенной памяти.

Поэтому лучше предоставить это делать компилятору, используя стандартный контейнер `std::vector`, который объявлен в заголовке `<vector>` Деструктор этого контейнера автоматически удаляет всю выделенную память под свои элементы.

Например,

```
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<float> f;
```

В программе вы используете цикл следующего вида

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        f[i] = (a + (i - 0.5) * h) / (1 + pow((a + (i - 0.5) * h), 2));
        s = s + f[i];
    }
```

Однако эта запись определения цикла неверная.
Во-первых, индексы в массивах (и в стандартном контейнере `std::vector`) начинаютя с 0.

Во-вторых, при использовании в качестве значения индекса значения переменной `n` приводит к обращению к памяти за пределами массива, что веден к неопределенному поведению программы.

Правильный диапазон индексов для массива, имеющего `n` элементов, это `[0, n)`, то есть `n` не входит в диапазон

Еще одна проблема связана с тем, что вы не инициализировали переменную `s`

```
float a, b, h, s, f[n];
              ^^^
```

Поэтому она имеет неопределенное значение, и использование ее в предложениях, как, например, данное предложение

```
s = s + f[i];
```

приведет к неопределенному результату.

Локальные переменные следует стараться определять в наименьшей области видимости там, где они используется. Иначе многочисленные объявления локальных переменных до их использования только запутывают читающего ваш код программиста.

С учетом всего сказанного программа может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main() 
{
    int n; 

    std::cout << "введите n: ";
    std::cin >> n; 

    float a, b;

    std::cout << "введите a: ";
    std::cin >> a; 
    std::cout << "введите b: ";
    std::cin >> b;

    if  ( a < b ) 
    { 
        std::vector<float> f;
        f.reserve( n );

        float h = ( b - a ) / n;

        float s = 0.0f;
        for  ( int i = 0; i <  n; i++ )
        {
            f.push_back( ( a + ( i - 0.5f ) * h ) / 
                         ( 1.0f + std::pow( ( a + ( i - 0.5f ) * h ), 2.0f) ) );
            s += f.back();
        }

        s *= h;

        std::cout << "(f1+f2+f3+..+fn)*h = " << s << std::endl;    
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "введены данные не удовлетворяют условие (a < b)" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за столь развернутый ответ и конечно же за то что уделили время на разъяснение моих остальных ошибок в коде. Насчет переменных, не знал, теперь буду учитывать это. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @Doe Не за что. Мы, начинающие программисты, должны помогать друг другу.:)

Answer (score 6):

Массивы должны быть постоянной длинны.

```
int arr[10];         //Правильно

const int size = 10;
int arr[size];       //Правильно

int size;
cin >> size;
int arr[size]        //Не правильно
```

Если вы заранее не знаете сколько вам нужно элементов используйте `std::vector`

```
#include<vector>
//...
vector<int> ints;
ints.push_back(42);
ints.push_back(314);
ints.push_back(271);
int i = ints[1]; //i = 314
```

В принципе, вы могли бы выделить массив нужного размера динамически

```
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int arr* = new int[size];
    arr[0] = 42;
    //...
    delete[] arr; //не забыть
```

Но лучше доверить это вектору. Он сделает то же самое, но его писали умные люди(*наверное*) и в нем нет никаких ошибок(*скорее всего*). Плюс вектор сам меняет свой размер, и вам не нужно следить за тем сколько памяти вы выделили.

Answer (score 5):

Как исправить код минимальными правками.

Добавляем в `include` vector:

```
#include <vector>
```

вместо объявления массива `float f[n];` пишем так `std::vector<float> f(n);` (создаст нужный "массив и заполнит нулями", классическое объявление f[n] на стеке не заполняет ими), а можно даже так `std::vector<float> f(n, 0);` - в этом случае явно укажем, что хотим заполнить нулями (можно выбрать любой другой заполнитель). Все остальное будет работать так, как ожидается. Не нужно боятся использовать вектор - это "правильный" массив в с++.

Comment: вопервых нужно размер вектора/массива на 1 больше `std::vector<float>(n + 1)` чтобы за пределы не вылезти с его кодом, и ещё я бы советовал динамический массив применить, раз уж только учится, а до контейнейров ещё дожить надо

Comment: ошибки в коде - это отдельная история. И нужно ли там добавить единицу, или пофиксить цикл - это нужно ещё подумать.

Но если человек учит именно с++, то нужно учить с++, а не си. Поэтому, нужно знать, что есть вектор на таком базовом уровне.

Comment: ну незнаю, просто концепция динаических массивов под которой я имел ввиду использование оператора `new` есть и в c++ - так что думаю не лишним будет подучить его, а дальше уже можно использовать и вектор, не забывая о том, что внутри он хранит динамический массив

Comment: Нулями он и так заполнится.

Comment: Если хочется именно динамический массив с new, тогда лучше сделать свой миникласс-велосипед. Но это уже сложнее. Плюс, нужно объяснять, что память ещё нужно чистить за собой.

"Нулями он и так заполнится." в данном случае 0 указан в обучающих целях.

Comment: Тогда бы лучше указать некую константу, а то из прочитанного получается, что в первом случае нулей там не будет, а будет не пойми что.

Answer (score 4):

Использовать динамические массивы

```
// объявляем массив и выделяем под него память
float * f = new float[n];
.................
// освобождаем выделенную память
delete [] f;
```

Answer (score 4):

3 варианта работы с массивами:

1) Массив константного размера

```
int a[10];
const n = 5;
int b[n];
```

2) Динамический массив

```
int n;
std::cin>>n;
int * a = new int[n];
//используем
delete[] a;
```

3) Вектор

```
#include<vector>
```

.

```
std::vector<int> v(n);
```